# SQL Rowcount vs Top

Tags: t-sql

What is the difference between

```
Set Rowcount X
```

And

```
Select Top X *
From Z
```

in TSQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Top can do a few more things for you.  For one, you can specify a percentage, instead of an integer.  You can also handle situations where ties in column values occur.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 10):

The main difference is that `top` will only effect the query you are running while `set rowcount` will persist with the connection and apply to all queries executed within that connection.

Comment: That fact is a tricky sob, issue. Is there any way to do set rowcount, that only affects the current query?

Comment: @crosenblum if you do a `SET ROWCOUNT 0` after the query, you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

In older versions of SQL Server (2005 and earlier I am not sure about 2008) you could not use a variable in a top statement so:

```
declare @rc int

set @rc=10

select top @rc * from myTable --Wont work

set rowcount @rc
select * from myTable --Will work
```

Answer (score 4):

2008 and above allows

```
declare @rc int

set @rc=10000

select top (@rc) * from myTable --will now work
```

but only if you use () this can be usefull to use hints like:

```
OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR (@rc= 15) )
```

at the end 
allowing to select everithing but optimize for a more common case